# Cordova phonegap issue when hiding keyboard?

Tags: cordova, keyboard

My app looks like this: [image]

If I press "Done", the keyboard hides and the view returns to its normal state. BUT, if the keyboard is on screen, and I tap in one of the radio button, the keyboard hides, and the whole view moves down, and there is a white space at bottom like this:

[image]

and then it returns to its normal state. Any clue about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This post saved my life: http://vizteck.com/blog/phonegap-issue-keyboard-scatters-ui-exit/

I just had to adjust which elements' position I wanted to modify.